# Email not translated inside a Celery Task

Tags: django, internationalization, celery

I have a celery task that sends an email asynchronously

```
from djcelery.common import respects_language

@task(ignore_result=True)
@respects_language
def async_send_activation_email(registration_profile):
    registration_profile.send_activation_email()
```

And the send activation email function

```
from django.core import context_processors

def send_activation_email(self):

    variables = {
                    'some_variable':'something',
        }
    context = context_processors.i18n(None) # Allows to easily get all the language information into context. None is passed as the request does not matter for this context_processor.


    # Subject
    # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
    subject = render_to_string(
        'user_manager/activation/email_subject.txt',
        variables,
        context
        )
            ...
```

context contains the correct informations (in my case LANGUAGE = 'fr', and other language options). Which is normal as they are correctly set by the `@respects_language` decorator.

but render_to_string use the fallback language anyway.

Any idea about what might be happening ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the language on something different than the render_to_string? Like printing a message or something like that to test if it is there. Another thing might be that the djcelery does not have locale path setup properly...

Comment: No a simple ugettext or ugettext_lazy doesn't work either. I shall look into the locale path issue

Comment: Np, I edited my answer so others would find the solution there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate('fr')
```

**EDIT**

Solution from comments on the question:

**check your locale paths**, they might be different when they are executed in celery.

Comment: look how @respects_language works https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/common.py

And has stated `get_language` returns `'fr'`